# text file data convert as data-set for natural language processing

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-analysis, nlp

I have to build model for natural language processing. For that i have data in text file and I want to convert that data into data-set for NLP model which predict bad and good in it.

I taken sample of emails data with contains some information and it is in text file.

I want to know how can i use that text file as data-set to my nlp model. please help me out

Comment: What have you tried yet?

Comment: Can you show the format of your data (which fields does the file contain?) as well as the details of your classification model (I assume it's a binary classification to predict if the content of an email is good or bad?)

Comment: I collected response from many people and stored it into text file. i did not get idea how can i manage it to feed to nlp model @ilkerkaran

Comment: I want to use email as input in which contains multiple field and and sub contained in emails check yes or no part and from some part want to extract data. @Cypherius

Comment: This is single mail contains in text file `As per our discussion I  need a conference room for technical session on monday 6th May. Please Acknowledge me on this request. for 12 peoples in which contains projector and mic`.